# vertically aligning something with flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

Coding a simple notification list with flexbox profile picture on the left, description on the top left of the picture with a timestamp on the bottom of the desc.

I can't get the span to vertically align to the bottom.

I know it must be something simple. Also, is this the best way of doing something like this with flexbox? eg. using a ul

```css
* {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    
        ul li {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
    
        ul li img {
            padding-right: 15px;
        }
    
        ul li div {
           display: flex;
           flex-direction: column;
        }
    
        ul li div p {
           vertical-align: top;
        }
    
        ul li div span {
           vertical-align: bottom;
        }
```

```html
<ul>
         <li>
            <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
              <div>
               <p>some thing</p>
               <span>timestamp</span>
           </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/s3jnLmxy/9/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing your code, only need to change the `ul li div` rule and then, there is not need for the final two: `ul li div p` and `ul li div span`:

```
ul li div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between; /* added line */
}
```

More info about `justify-content` property [here](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/j/justify-content/)

---

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

ul li img {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

ul li div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
    <div>
      <p>some thing</p>
      <span>timestamp</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add margin top auto to the span and you can remove the vertical align rules - `ul li div p` is removed

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  background: green
}

ul li img {
  padding-right: 15px;
}

ul li div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: gray;
}

ul li div span {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <img style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
    <div>
      <p>some thing</p>
      <span>timestamp</span>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

For completeness I will add the other solution as well

Add `justify-content: space-between;` to the flex container (div). This will work in this particular situation however depending on your content (different than current) this may not work.

Comment: that's awesome. thanks. is this the best way of doing it?

Comment: For what you want in this scenario this is the proper way to do it, there are other ways of doing the same since you have direction as column, it all works. Using margin top will always push it to the bottom no matter how many items you have before it